# Where are method options defined in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

```
# Transform the model name into a more humane format, using I18n. By default,
# it will underscore then humanize the class name
#
#   BlogPost.model_name.human # => "Blog post"
#
# Specify +options+ with additional translating options.
```

I found the above while digging through Rails trying to discover what exactly are the options for translating.  I can find lots of references that say, use +options+ but can find no definitive method where these options are defined.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are talking about is `ActiveRecord::Base#human`

```
# Transform the model name into a more humane format, using I18n. By default,
# it will underscore then humanize the class name
#
#   BlogPost.model_name.human # => "Blog post"
#
# Specify +options+ with additional translating options.
def human(options={})
  return @human unless @klass.respond_to?(:lookup_ancestors) &&
                       @klass.respond_to?(:i18n_scope)

  defaults = @klass.lookup_ancestors.map do |klass|
    klass.model_name.underscore.to_sym
  end

  defaults << options.delete(:default) if options[:default]
  defaults << @human

  options.reverse_merge! :scope => [@klass.i18n_scope, :models], :count => 1, :default => defaults
  I18n.translate(defaults.shift, options)
end
```

that internally relies on `I18n.translate`. Thus `options` can be any option supported by the I18n method, including `:scope`, `:default` and more.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations

The `options` argument also depends on the I18n backend you are currently using.

Comment: thanks, that sort of helped - sounds like the options aren't defined in the docs for a reason